Template argument deduction with braced init list
Look at this simple snippet, it compiles:
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Pair {
    A a;
    B b;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(Pair<A, B> p) {
}

int main() {
    foo(Pair{1, 2.0});
}

However, if I remove Pair from the call foo, it doesn't compile:
int main() {
    foo({1, 2.0}); // does not compile: cannot deduce template parameters
}

Is there some kind of trick to make foo({1, 2.0}); compile?
Note, I don't insist on using Pair. I'd like to have a solution which allows me to use the syntax of foo({some_a, some_b}) (where some_a and some_b can have any type, so foo has to be a template).
Note, this question is not a duplicate of Template class and automatic deduction or Initialize a class with brace-enclosed initializer list. If you check out the answers to these questions: none of the answers solves this problem. Both of the duplicate question involves same types, and using arrays. But in this case, there is no array, and Pair<A, B> can be a different type depending on A and B.

foo<int, double>({ 1, 2.0 });

Which compiler?

Voted to reopen, based on the added note.

{..} has no types and can only be deduced as T(&)[N] or std::initilizer_list<T>.
So as A/B are different types, you cannot use deduction for that.
Having the different overloads might be an alternative, if appropriate (which is not in your case):
void foo(Pair<int, double> p) {/*..*/}
void foo(Pair<int, int> p) {/*..*/}
// ...


Not exactly what you wanted, but you can omit the mention of Pair by specifying the template parameter types for foo explicitly.
In order to avoid using hard coded type names, you can use decltype:
int    some_a = 1;
double some_b = 2.0;
foo<decltype(some_a), decltype(some_b)>({ some_a, some_b });

Live demo

foo(Pair{some_a, some_b}) seems cleaner.

@Jarod42 I agree, but the OP asked specifically to avoid mentioning Pair presumably because it might be some other pair-like class. Am I wrong ?

@wohlstad: The situation is the opposite: foo only accepts a Pair, so I like to skip writing it as it is unnecessary.

@geza in that case I don't think it is possible (at least not as you wanted). My solution does allow to omit Pair but it is not cleaner, maybe the opposite... you decide.
